# Load the Progress bar for each image View and Table View Cell(Contains ImageView) in ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, progress, uitableview

Totally i have Five ImageView and one Table View With 10 Table View Cell(Contains Image View),here i want to load the progress bar for each image view & Table View Cell While image loading.i had already done the progress bar by MMProgress but that is loading for Entire View but i want to load the progress bar for Each imageView & Table View Cell,help me
For ImageView like this

[image]

In Table View Like This

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You downloading images from the web, if I've understood correctly, so u may use this library https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage It's very useful and simple in use. Just use this method to receive downloading progress:

```
   SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                  options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                     // progression tracking code
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                     if (image) {
                         // do something with image
                     }
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to track the progress of your downloads via your data model which should be based on indexPath. When a download makes some progress and that progress is significant (say 5%), simply reload the affected row by indexPath. It will then update the cells progress bar because you will set its value to the current progress value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when it is called as a result of the reload.

To get started and to check this is what you want, just reload the whole table to start with when any progress is made which is significant. Then when it looks roughly what you are after, implement the more efficient solution.